# Where to call the API the MVC pattern?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am developing a mobile app with Javascript on the client side and rails as the api.

I am using Monocle by Tapquo, a MVC javascript framework. I need to call my server to retrieve data in `json` format.

Should I rewrite the model class method using ajax request instead of the default local storage calls so when I create an object, the call is made in the model? Or should I make the calls inside the controller?

What is the convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Tapquo, but most MVC implementations that are network savvy are really MVC-S, where the S is "service".  In other words, you implement a service layer in your app that your controller calls to fetch the model that it wants to work with.

Comment: Monocle is a pure mvc framework so it does include the service layer. However, QuoJs (dependency) does. You are saying that I should make the calls in the controller? The thing is my app will be entirely hosted on the server so I don't create local models. I thought that by rewriting the create method to create an instance on the api trough the service, the code would be easier to maintain.

Comment: I guess it depends a bit on the workflow you expect. If  you're *always* going to create a model using the service, then put the service call in the model. I personally find it muddies the water a bit, since I almost always want to be able to create a 'blank' model that I can stuff with data and post to the service. So I normally don't have models with internal dependencies to services or to an http pipe.

Comment: I have experimented with your solution and decided to create a service that will populate my local cache on initialize.